# sweet alert2: how to get autofocus on input?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

using [sweetalert2@8](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)

Using sweet alert for a search box with below code. Autofocus works on Chrome but not on Safari & Firefox. How can we fix this?

```
swal.fire({
    // title: "Search",
    type: "question",
    html: '<form id="searchForm" method="post" action="/search">' +
        "<input type='hidden' />" +
        '<input autofocus class="form-control" type="text" name="search_box" placeholder="Seach..."></form>',
    confirmButtonText: "Search",
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
    preConfirm: function (value) {
        document.getElementById("searchForm").submit();
        return new Promise(resolve => {
        })
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding JavaScript code to [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill) the missing functionality you do not get in other browsers. Sweetalert2 also has a browser compatibility page [here](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2#browser-compatibility) that says it's compatible in all major browsers. But also suggest using the following script tag to import the needed polyfill.

```html
<!-- Include a polyfill for ES6 Promises (optional) for IE11 -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.js"></script>
```

As far as the **autofocus** attribute, it is also supported by all major browser according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/autofocus). You could try using a JavaScript event when the alert is fired that sets the autofocus property.

```
document.getElementById('myInput').autofocus = true;
```

You can also try to polyfill the autofocus property itself with this example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/qZHxv/).

Comment: Indeed, according to MDN it should work , but still it doesn't. Adding document.getElementById("searchForm").autofocus = true or focus() or select() also doesn't help. Also tried an ID on the search_box instead of the form, no luck on Safari 12.0.2

Comment: Thank you for the hints, found a solution based on your inputs: Adding a second ID to the input with name search_box (e.g. id="searchBoxId"), and then (using jquery) $("#searchBoxId").focus();  after the swal.fire() call does the trick!

Comment: @Davy I'm glad I could help put you on the right track!

Answer (score 2):

Another option here would be to use the native `.focus()` method on input inside `didOpen` parameter of SweetAlert2:

```js
Swal.fire({
  ...
  didOpen: () => {
    Swal.getHtmlContainer().querySelector('.custom-input').focus()
  }
})
```